# How variables on websites are managed without clashing the values of different users

Tags: php, variables

```
<?php
    $value = $_POST['value'];   //line 1
    /* Some piece of code which really takes some time to execute */
    echo "Value is :" .$value;  // line 1000
?>
```

In the above php code I have a variable $value which holds a user input value.
Suppose this particular page is accessed by multiple users at a time, how can the value of the variable remain unaffected for a particular user?
Let me make my question clear. 
Suppose if user 'A' access my page and sets the value of variable $value as 10 (line 1), 
while executing line no 1000 he should get the value what he entered to be displayed as the output. 
I know it wont take much time to reach the compiler from line 1 to 1000 but considering the worst case
if the code in between line 1 and 1000 takes some time for execution (say 2 sec) and by that time another user "B" logs in and 
set the value of variable $value as 99 (line 1), will the value of the second user affect the value of the first user?
I have tried this one but i didn't get any error like what i expect. I would like to know why it is like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> remain unaffected for a particular user?

Each php script gets his own thread.

A user can NOT change stuff from another user.

Or lets say one PHP Script that is run twice can NOT manipulate the other.

(Only if you are using sessions and the same user call the script twice in a browser where each TAB has not his own session)

Its little bit like you starting a progamm twice.

Answer (score -1):

The moment you do: `$value = $_POST['value'];` the value of `$_POST['value']` is copied into `$value`: not by reference but by value; thus even if after 20,000 lines something happens to `$_POST['value']`, so long as the Page is not reloaded; `$value` still contains the original/initial data assigned to it; *unless you or someone else has access to* `$value` *and did something like:* `$value = 'new value';` *Other that those, (and so long as* `$value` *is not overridden anywhere in your code:)* `$value` *will still stick around and retain its value till the end of your script.*